# iphone - IUWebView javascript scrollIntoView()

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

I have a simple UIWebView with simple HTML. At the end I place a javascript function:

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
var x = document.getElementById('SEARCHRESULT');
if (x != null) x.scrollIntoView(true);}
</script>
```

To force the view to scroll to a region. It doesn't seem to work.

Does the UIWebView not support this simple javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a "`}`" without matching "`{`" at the end of the second line. If this is also the case in the code you're actually using, the javascript will not be executed because of this syntax error.